# Reuse decorated mapper with Mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

I'm using MapStruct 1.3.0.Final to convert Dtos into POJOs and vice versa with the **spring** value into *mapstruct.defaultComponentModel* option. To avoid  stackoverflow errors due to bidirectional relations I have followed the next link:

[Mapping With Cycles](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/tree/master/mapstruct-mapping-with-cycles)

Some of those converters have been decorated following the instructions included in:

[Customizing Mappers Using Decorators](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappers-using-decorators)

The question is:

How can I use decorated converters in other ones using the option **uses**?

Following the example included in the second link, I have tested:

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring", uses={PersonMapper.class})
public interface OtherMapper

@Mapper(componentModel="spring", uses={PersonMapperDecorator.class})
public interface OtherMapper
```

But I have not achieved that `OtherMapper` uses the `PersonMapperDecorator`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the MapStruct decorator with the Spring component model you only need to work with the mapper, not with the decorator.

In your example you should use

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = PersonMapper.class)
public interface OtherMapper {
    ...
}
```

This would inject the `PersonMapper` decorator, with the injected original mapper (`PersonMapper`).